# Sklearn Naive Bayes with multiple features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

### Background

I'm struggling to implement a Naive Bayes classifier in `python` with `sklearn` across multiple features.

The features I have are:

1. Title - some short text
2. Description - some longer text
3. Timestamp - a float representing an hour of the day (e.g. 18.0 = 6:00PM, 11.5 = 11:30AM)

The labels/classes are categorical strings: e.g. "Class1", "Class2", "Class3"

### Aim

My goal is to use the 3 features in order to construct a Naive Bayes classifier for 3 features in order to predict the class label. I specifically wish to use all of the features at the same time, i.e. not simply the *description* feature.

### Initial Approach

I have setup some pre-processing pipelines using `sklearn` as follows:

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing, naive_bayes, feature_extraction, pipeline, model_selection, compose,

text_columns = ['title', 'description']
time_columns = ['timestamp']

# get an 80-20 test-train split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(train[text_columns + time_columns], train['class'], test_size=0.2, random_state=RANDOM_STATE)

# convert the text data into vectors
text_pipeline = pipeline.Pipeline([
    ('vect', feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer()),
])

# preprocess by scaling the data, and binning the data
time_pipeline = pipeline.Pipeline([
    ('scaler', preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('bin', preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=6, encode='ordinal', strategy='quantile')),
])

# combine the pre-processors
preprocessor = compose.ColumnTransformer([
    ('text', text_pipeline, text_columns),
    ('time', time_pipeline, time_columns),
])

clf = pipeline.Pipeline([
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('clf', naive_bayes.MultinomialNB()),
])
```

Here `train` is a `pandas` dataframe with the features and labels, read straight from a `.csv` file like this:

```
ID,title,description,timestamp,class
1,First Title String,"A description of the first title",13.0,Class1
2,Second Title String,"A description of the second title",17.5,Class2
```

Also note that I'm not setting most of the params for the transformers/classifiers, as I want to use a grid-search to find the optimum ones later on.

### The problem

When I call `clf.fit(X_train, y_train)`, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_7500/3039541201.py in <module>
     33 
     34 # x = pd.DataFrame(text_pipeline.fit_transform(X_train['mean_checkin_time']))
---> 35 x = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
     36 # # print the number of features
     37 

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    388         """
    389         fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
--> 390         Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    391         with _print_elapsed_time("Pipeline", self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):
    392             if self._final_estimator != "passthrough":

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    346                 cloned_transformer = clone(transformer)
    347             # Fit or load from cache the current transformer
--> 348             X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
    349                 cloned_transformer,
    350                 X,

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    347 
    348     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 349         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    350 
    351     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    891     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    892         if hasattr(transformer, "fit_transform"):
--> 893             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    894         else:
    895             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    697         self._record_output_indices(Xs)
    698 
--> 699         return self._hstack(list(Xs))
    700 
    701     def transform(self, X):

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _hstack(self, Xs)
    789         else:
    790             Xs = [f.toarray() if sparse.issparse(f) else f for f in Xs]
--> 791             return np.hstack(Xs)
    792 
    793     def _sk_visual_block_(self):

<__array_function__ internals> in hstack(*args, **kwargs)

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in hstack(tup)
    344         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
    345     else:
--> 346         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
    347 
    348 

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 2 and the array at index 1 has size 3001
```

I have the following shapes for `X_train` and `y_train`:

```
X_train: (3001, 3)
y_train: (3001,)
```

### Steps Taken

#### Individual Features

I can use the same pipelines with individual features (by altering the `text_features` and `time_features` arrays), and get a perfectly fine classifier. E.g. only using the "title" field, or only using the "timestamp". Unfortunately, these individual features are not accurate enough, so I would like to use all the features to build a more accurate classifier. The issue seems to be when I attempt to combine more than one feature.

I'm open to potentially using multiple Naive Bayes classifiers, and trying to multiply the probabilities together to get some overall probability, but I honestly have no clue how to do that, and I'm sure I'm just missing something simple here.

#### Dropping the Time Features

I have tried running only the `text_features`, i.e. "title" and "description", and I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_7500/1900884535.py in <module>
     33 
     34 # x = pd.DataFrame(text_pipeline.fit_transform(X_train['mean_checkin_time']))
---> 35 x = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
     36 # # print the number of features
     37 

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    392             if self._final_estimator != "passthrough":
    393                 fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
--> 394                 self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
    395 
    396         return self

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    661             Returns the instance itself.
    662         """
--> 663         X, y = self._check_X_y(X, y)
    664         _, n_features = X.shape
    665 

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py in _check_X_y(self, X, y, reset)
    521     def _check_X_y(self, X, y, reset=True):
    522         """Validate X and y in fit methods."""
--> 523         return self._validate_data(X, y, accept_sparse="csr", reset=reset)
    524 
    525     def _update_class_log_prior(self, class_prior=None):

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    579                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
    580             else:
--> 581                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    582             out = X, y
    583 

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
    979     y = _check_y(y, multi_output=multi_output, y_numeric=y_numeric)
    980 
--> 981     check_consistent_length(X, y)
    982 
    983     return X, y

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    330     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    331     if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 332         raise ValueError(
    333             "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: %r"
    334             % [int(l) for l in lengths]

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 3001]
```

And I have the following shapes:

```
X_train: (3001, 2)
y_train: (3001,)
```

#### Reshaping the Labels

I have also tried reshaping `y_train` variable by calling it wrapped in `[]` like so:

```py
# new
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(train[text_columns + time_columns], train[['class']], test_size=0.2, random_state=RANDOM_STATE)

# previous
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(train[text_columns + time_columns], train['class'], test_size=0.2, random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
```

so that the resultant shapes are:

```
X_train: (3001, 3)
y_train: (3001, 1)
```

But unfortunately this doesn't appear to fix this.

#### Removing Naive Bayes Classifier

When I remove the final step of the pipeline (the `naivebayes.MultinomialNB()`), and I remove the `text_features` ("timestamp" feature), then I can build a pre-processor that works just fine for the text. I.e. I can pre-process the text fields ("title", "description"), but when I add the classifier, I get the error above under "Dropping the Time Features".

Answer (score 0):

When vectorizing multiple text features, you should create `CountVectorizer` (or `TfidfVectorizer`) instances for every feature:

```py
title_pipeline = pipeline.Pipeline([
    ('vect', feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer()),
])
description_pipeline = pipeline.Pipeline([
    ('vect', feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer()),
])
preprocessor = compose.ColumnTransformer([
    ('title', title_pipeline, text_columns[0]),
    ('description', description_pipeline, text_columns[1]),
    ('time', time_pipeline, time_columns),
])
```

P.S. The combination of `CountVectorizer` and `TfidfTransformer` is equivalent to `TfidfVectorizer`. Also, you may just skip tf-idf weighting and use only `CountVectorizer` for `MultinomialNB`.